# Noise color in multidimensional frequency space - is there an angular effect or dependence?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, noise, white-noise

I understand that if there is a non-constant level of noise in one-dimensional frequency space, e.g. noise variance increasing linearly with frequency gives "blue noise" in the iFFT space. By extension, the same applies to a two- or three-dimensional frequency space, where blue noise is generated if the noise variance increases linearly in a radial sense. However: what happens in iFFT space if noise variance also has other dependencies, such as angular, or local, random ones, in addition to a radial dependence? Thanks.